# Android Emulator - how to get Geo Location?

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, jquery-mobile

I am using 'jquery-ui-map' for an android app. My emulator is Google API Level 13 version 3.2. My Javascript code is :

```
$('#gps_map').live("pageshow", function() {
$('#map_canvas_2').gmap('refresh');
$('#map_canvas_2').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
        $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('get', 'map').panTo(latlng);
        $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('search', { 'location': latlng }, function(results, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                $('#from').val(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Unable to get current position');
    }
});});
```

This code always fails to get location. I can't see the GPS icon in the emulator. I tried setting all possible permissions, tried setting the latlong coordinates with geo fix method but nothing works. Is there ANY way by which geo location can work on android ?

Comment: ok forget about 'jquery-ui-map', can you please point me to the correctly handling GPS location in an emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(pos, status) {
        if (status === "OK") {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', latLng);
        } else {
            // error msg
        }
    }, { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
```

Adding a longer timout in options, like shown above fixes the issue. The example shows a long timeout: 10 seconds.